# How to access a particular element of dynamically updated knockout observableArray without using foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Why am i able to access only one (i.e. `'member_A'`) property of a observableArray's Element with `<input>`of HTML.

I am trying to add new abc() object into observableArray `"list_of_abc"` on click of button `"ADD To List of abc"` and show the recently added object's properties (that are `member_A` and `member_B`) in `input` boxes.
My code does add new abc() object to observableArray `"list_of_abc"` but i am unable to display newly added object's members(that are `"member_A"` and `"member_B"`) in `input` boxes of `HTML`.

**ViewModel**

```
     function abc(var1,var2)
    {
        this.member_A = ko.observable(var1);
        this.member_B = ko.observable(var2);
    }

    function Home()
    {
        this.list_of_abc = ko.observableArray();
        this.last_added_index = ko.observable();
        this.addTolist_of_abc = function()
                                {
                                    var len = this.list_of_abc().length;
                                    this.last_added_index(len);
                                    this.list_of_abc.push(new abc("Element"+len,len));      
                                };

    }

    ko.applyBindings(new Home());
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
            <button data-bind = "click: addTolist_of_abc">ADD To list_of_abc</button>
    </div>

<p>Last Added abc's object</p> <br>
member_A's value:  <input data-bind="value: list_of_abc()[$root.last_added_index()].member_A" />  <br>     
 member_B's value:   <input data-bind="value: list_of_abc()[$root.last_added_index()].member_B" />
```

**Output**
http://jsfiddle.net/himanshudhiman/3r0g0wak/1/

In output, I am getting only first variable 'member_A' in input box.
Second Input Box is Blank.
Moreover, i have to click on "ADD To List of abc" button twice to get the member_A displayed in input box.

I wish to ***access and modify*** a particular abc object form list_of_abc observableArray, how could i do that with a given number as observableArray index.

**So is there any way to access observableArray's element directly by using their index instead of looping through whole Array by putting foreach on observableArray.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want your code to do, so I guessed you wanted to be able to enter new items into a list. With that in mind, I added a `newItem` member to the viewmodel and bound its members to the input boxes. The `addToList` method copies from those values into a new element of saved items.

I added a `foreach`-bound div so you could see what's in the list. I also changed variable names to comply with JavaScript naming conventions, and changed the constructors into ordinary object-returning functions.

**Update:** I added a section which will allow you to edit an existing row by choosing its index. You can still add new elements, and the list of indexes will adjust accordingly.

```js
function abc(var1, var2) {
  var self = {
    member_A: ko.observable(var1),
    member_B: ko.observable(var2)
  };
  return self;
}

function homeModel() {
  var self = {
    list: ko.observableArray([
      abc('one', '1'),
      abc('two', '2')
    ]),
    newItem: abc('', ''),
    lastAdded: ko.observable(),
    addToList: function(item) {
      self.lastAdded(self.list().length);
      self.list.push(abc(self.newItem.member_A(), self.newItem.member_B()));
    },
    editIndex: ko.observable(),
    listIndex: ko.computed({
      read: function() {
        var result = [],
          len = self.list().length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          result.push(i);
        }
        return result;
      },
      deferEvaluation: true
    })
  };
  return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(homeModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button data-bind="click: addToList">ADD To List ofabc</button>
</div>
<input data-bind="value: newItem.member_A" />
<input data-bind="value: newItem.member_B" />
<div data-bind="foreach:list"> <span data-bind="text:member_A"></span>, <span data-bind="text:member_B"></span>

  <br />
</div>
<div>Index:
  <select data-bind="options:listIndex, value:editIndex"></select>
  <br />
  <!-- ko if: list().length-1 >= editIndex() -->Editing <span data-bind="text:editIndex"></span>

  <input data-bind="value: list()[editIndex()].member_A" />
  <input data-bind="value: list()[editIndex()].member_B" />
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: Roy, I have edited my post to clear what am i trying to achieve. Please have a look at changed post

Comment: @HimanshuDhiman I have updated my answer. See how I have bound the editing inputs.